# Python inner class self

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, class

The inner class does method requires a self-variable but it was already given.
The main idea is to have a django database model like module.
To have a User class that contains the user's data and to query all the results with the same class

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, password):
        self.name = name
        self.password = sha256.encrypt(password)

    def verify_password(self, psw):
        return sha256.verify(self.password, psw)

    def save(self):
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO user (name, password) VALUES (?,?)", (self.name, self.password))
        conn.commit()

    class query(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.data = cur.execute("SELECT * from user")
            self.test = "test"

        def first(self):
            return self.data.fetchone()

        def all(self):
            return self.data.fetchall()


print(User.query.all())
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zsolt\Desktop\api\model.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(User.query.all())
TypeError: all() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this answer I've simplified your code into a more generic snippet:

```
class A:
  class B:
    def __init__(self):
      print("query the database")

    def first(self):
      print("return the first match only")

    def all(self):
      print("return all matches")

A.B.all()
```

In the highlighted line, you are never creating an instance of class B! The marked line should be `A.B().all()` instead, creating an object of type `A.B` and then invoking a method on that instance.

*Note: In your snippet you need to change `User.query.all()` to `User.query().all()`.*